# Rate My Script: Finding Flash Files Embedded in Office Files

Tags: flash, batch-file, windows-xp, ms-office

Can anyone improve on this? Requires Sysinternals Strings

```
date /T >N:\output.txt
net use z: /delete
net use z: \\svr-002\rmstudentwork
@cd /d "z:\"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.xls | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.ppt | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.doc | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.xlsx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.pptx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.docx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"

date /T >>N:\output.txt
net use z: /delete /yes >>N:\output.txt
net use z: \\svr-003\rmstudentwork
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.xls | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.ppt | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.doc | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.xlsx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.pptx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
"N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe" -s *.docx | findstr \.swf >> "N:\output.txt"
net use z: /delete /yes
```

Basically it mounts a share as a network drive then runs through the share looking for swf files inside office documents.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a batch file expert, but I think you could:

- Store repeated paths in variables:

  ```
  set STRINGS="N:\Scripts and Reg Frags\FindEmbededFlashFiles\strings.exe"
  set OUTFILE=N:\output.txt
  ```
- Replace repeated commands with a [FOR](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop, e.g.:

  ```
  for /r z:\ %%f in (*.xls *.ppt *.doc *.xlsx *.pptx *.docx) do (
    %STRINGS% -q "%%f" | findstr \.swf >> %OUTFILE%
  )
  ```

  (Note that this loop also replaces `@cd /d "z:\"` and the `-s` parameter of strings.exe.)

***Disclaimer:*** I'm writing this off the top of my head, so the suggested code may not work or may need additional fine-tuning. Anyway, I hope this will give you the idea.